# PIL image rotation and background issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to rotate my transparent gif using the PIL rotate() but I am getting a diamond after rotating it.

**Similar problems on SO** were solved by using

```py
transparency = img.info['transparency']
img.save('result.gif',transparency=transparency)
```

or by using

```py
img.save('result.gif', **img.info)
```

But I am getting the following results as in the images.

[image: Original][image: Rotated]

My code is

```py
from PIL import Image

file = 'change2_1.gif'

with Image.open(file) as im:
    transparency = im.info['transparency']
    img = im.rotate(45, expand=True)
    img.save('result.gif', transparency=transparency)
```

Answer (score 0):

Post edited: Try to use this to make black backgroud transparent

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('img.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

with Image.open(file) as im:
transparency = im.info['transparency']
img = im.rotate(90, expand=True)
img.save('result.gif', transparency=transparency)

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 0 and item[1] == 0 and item[2] == 0:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)
```

Comment: But how should I make it work if I want to rotate it to any angle given by the user.Should I try to crop or something after rotating ???

Comment: Do you want remove black background?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the image transparent even after rotation

Comment: I was thinking of either cropping or maybe creating a transparent image with Image.create and then pasting the rotated image inside but I am not familiar with PIL and not sure if it is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having a black frame after rotation, simply change the default mode ('RGB') to 'RGBA' after opening :

```
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGBA')
img.rotate(90, expand = True)
```